# Converting CSV to string in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv into a space-delimited string variable in bash and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the info into a string.

How would I go about reading in and converting a csv that looks like this:

```
number1
number2
number3
etc
```

to a string `"number1 number2 number3 etc"`?

Thank you!

Comment: `tr '\n' ' '< file.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert all newlines to spaces using `tr`:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <file.csv
```

If you want to reuse the output, save in a variable:

```
out=$(tr '\n' ' ' <file.csv)
```

Now you can get the output string by using `"$out"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV data is in the file "file.csv", the command

```
foo=$(echo `cat file.csv`)
```

should put the concatenated contents of "file.csv" in the variable "foo".